# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) + 2$

Tags: recursion

$T(0) = 1,
T(1) = 0$

I ain't able to get answer from any of the methods.

**Substitution:**

$T(n) = x^n $

\begin{align}
& x^n = x^{n-1} + 2x^{n-2} + 2 \\
& x^2 = x + 2 + 2x^2\\
& x^2 + x  + 2 =0
\end{align}

solving this I will get a complex root.

\begin{align}
x & = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-8}}{2}
x & = \frac{-1 \pm 7i}{2}
\end{align}

Now how to go further.

**General:**

\begin{align}
T(2) & = 4\\
T(3) & = 6\\
T(4) & = 16\\
T(5) & = 30\\
T(6) & = 64\\
T(7) & = 126\\
T(8) & = 256
\end{align}

From this i can deduce **if $n$ is even** then $2^n$.
 I cant deduce for **if $n$ is odd**.

Comment: When you divide both sides of your first line by $x^{n-2}$ you get $$x^2+2+\frac{2}{x^{n-2}}.$$ So, what went wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to solve for complex root

Comment: Solve the homogeneous recurrence $T_n=T_{n-1}+2T_{n-2}$ first.

Comment: @user539887 sorry , I didn't notice it's is not linear equation. I don't know how to solve it further. If i am right then there is some set of conditions depending on the equation. I studied the concept 2 years back now have no idea how to do such questions.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: what about non homeogeneous part ?
There are some set of conditions right depending on the root. If you can provide me some reference i would be able to solve this.

Comment: It is a *linear nonhomogeneous* recurrence equation.

Comment: Okay when would it be non linear then .T(n) = T(n/2) is it linear or non linear ?

Comment: $T(n)=T(n/2)$ is not a recurrence relation (in the usually sense of the word). An example of a nonlinear recurrence relation is $T(n)=(T(n-1))^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $U(n) - 1 = T(n)$ and the equation is
$$
U(n+2) = U(n-1) + 2U(n)
$$
let as you do $U(n) = x^n$ and we get
$$
x^{n+2} = x^{n-1}+2x^n
$$ or we need to solve
$$
x^2-x-2 = 0
$$

hence
$$
x = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{1/4+8/4} = \frac{1 \pm 3}{2}
$$

So
$$
U(n) = A 2^n + B (-1)^n
$$ and
$$
T(n) = A 2^n + B (-1)^n - 1
$$
So
$$
T(0) = A+B-1 = 1
$$ and
$$
T(1) = 2A-B -1 = 0
$$ gives
$$
A = 1, \,B=1
$$
And we conclude
$$
T(n) = 2^n+(-1)^n-1
$$

Comment: Thanx for showing the whole process now i am to solve all type of questions.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** try to make it homogeneous, from
$$T(n) = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) + 2$$
$$T(n+1) = T(n) + 2T(n-1) + 2$$
we have 
$$T(n)-T(n+1)=T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) - T(n) - 2T(n-1) \iff \\
T(n+1)-2T(n)-T(n-1)+2T(n-2)=0$$
leading to characteristic polynomial
$$x^3-2x^2-x+2=0 \iff (x-2)(x-1)(x+1)=0$$

Comment: +1 This really helps me .

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem: note that you have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\ a_n \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n}\\ a_{n-1} \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: how did u get that matrix?

Comment: @KritiSahu: From the recursive definition. $a_{n+1}=a_n+2\cdot a_{n-1}+2\cdot 1$, $a_n=a_n+0\cdot a_{n-1}+0\cdot 1$ and $1=0\cdot a_n+0\cdot a_{n-1}+1\cdot 1$.